# user.home directory is changed when calling through jboss7 windows service

Tags: java, windows-services, jboss7.x

I've recently converted my jboss 7 server to windows service. In a java class i was using

```
System.getProperty("user.home"); method.
```

Previously when i print the value of the above code, the output was my user home directory but now when installed the JBoss7 as a windows service it prints the value

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
```

Don't know the reason for such random behavior.

Comment: What do you expect when running as a service?

Comment: the same user directory which was coming earlier cause i've few files kept on the user home directory which is used through out the application.

Comment: The `user.home` property [is a mess on Windows](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4787931) anyway. I wonder, how you could ever actually find your home directory with this property.

Comment: But when i was using Jboss6 as as windows service it was working in the expected manner, but why its not giving the same result with Jboss7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, i just changed the user account to access the service and it redirects to my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

The property `user.home` depends on the current user logged in in the system.

When starting the application server as a service under windows another user is used than the user used during development. That's the reason why you have two different values for the property.